# How to add commas to a string between characters that aren't the same?

Tags: javascript, string

The problem:

> The input data for this exercise will be two dimensional array (an array of arrays), where each sub-array will have two numeric values.
>
> The first will be the value to repeat, the second will be the amount of times to repeat that value.
>
> Create a function named `repeatNumbers` that will return a string with each of the given values repeated the appropriate number of times, if there are multiple sets of values each set should be separated by a comma. If there is only one set of values then you should omit the comma.

My code so far:

```js
const repeatNumbers = function(arr) {
  let numbersRepeated = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i][1]; j++) {
      numbersRepeated += arr[i][0];
    }
  }
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return numbersRepeated;
  } else {
    return numbersRepeated;
  }
}

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3]
]));
```

I am getting the correct output but obviously all in one string with no commas so far: running the above outputs:

```
11222
```

How can I make it so that a comma is inserted between the different numbers no matter what inputs are or how many sub arrays there are?

For the above example:

```
11, 222
```

Comment: `numbersRepeated  += ","` at the end of the first for loop

Comment: What is the expected output for [[2, 123],[2, 123]]?

Comment: by subarray, the array will always be in the `[x, y], [a, b], ...`format right? as oppossed to `[[x, y], [a, b], [...]], [[y, x], [b,a], [...]]`, thus continuously scaling the array to a larger multidimensional array.

Comment: Note your `if()` at the end is redundant since you return the same thing for both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert the code to add the comma at the start of the outer looop (i.e. when it loops each set). But include a check for whether there is any previous text in the output, otherwise it'll add a comma *before* the first entry.

Like this:

```js
const repeatNumbers = function(arr) {
  let numbersRepeated = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (numbersRepeated != "") numbersRepeated += ",";
    
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i][1]; j++) {
      numbersRepeated += arr[i][0];
    }
  }
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return numbersRepeated;
  } else {
    return numbersRepeated;
  }
}

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3]
]));
```

Comment: An upvote after 5 seconds must come from someone who didn't read the answer...

Comment: @trincot lol I'll take what I can get. But I think I've answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add the value to an array and the use join with a comma and space. That way you don't have to check for the length.

```js
const repeatNumbers = function(arr) {
  let total = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let numbersRepeated = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i][1]; j++) {
      numbersRepeated += arr[i][0];
    }
    total.push(numbersRepeated);
  }
  return total.join(', ');
}

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3]
]));

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 2]
]));

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [99, 4]
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `map()` the array to new array of the repeating values and use `join()`

```js
const repeatNumbers = function(arr) {
  return arr.map(e => e[0].toString().repeat(e[1])).join(', ')
}


console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3]
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a good case to use the native `repeat` method, and then `map` and `join` to concatenate those results into a comma separated string:

```js
const repeatNumbers = (pairs) => 
    pairs.map(([what, count]) => String(what).repeat(count)).join();

// demo
console.log(repeatNumbers([ [123, 2], [87, 3] ]));
```

Comment: As per the original example in the question, input of `[ [2, 123], [3, 87] ]` should yield `2` repeated 123 times, and `3` repeated 87 times. You've got it the other way round :-)